# Django db search keywords, not exact text

Tags: python, django

Given the search term "big file larger desk", how would I search for 1) any of the results; and 2) all of the results.

The search I am currently doing is:

```
results = Path.objects.filter(path__icontains=search)
```

What I need to do is something along the lines of:

```
results = Path.objects.filter(path__icontains=search.split())
```

How would I do both of these? (OR or AND)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that you are not actually hitting the database when you filter, so you can do the filtering multiple times without losing to much performance, a first approach can be:

```
results = Path.objects.all()
for s in search.split():
    results = results.filter(path__icontains = s)
```

that is for AND ans you can use a similar approach for or.

Comment: This won't work as posted; you need to reassign the results of the filter calls to itself. `results = results.filter(...)`

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from operator import or_

# AND - use argument unpacking
Path.objects.filter(*(Q(path__icontains=s)
                      for s in search.split()))

# OR - use reduce
Path.objects.filter(reduce(or_, (Q(path__icontains=s)
                                 for s in search.split())))
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to search on multiple fields as well, like either find the text on title or description or whatever?

Comment: It depends on your exact requirements, but you probably just want to have a `Q` object for each field, joining them with the `|` operator, something like `Q(title__i contains=s) | Q(description__i contains=s)` inside of the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Build a list comprehension and use the reduce function:

```
keywords = search.strip().split()
list_path_qs = [Q(path__icontains=x) for x in keywords]
final_q = reduce(operator.and_, list_path_qs)
results = Path.objects.filter(final_q)[:100]
```